# How big are the rocky/icy cores of Jovian planets?

Tags: planet, gas-giants

The size of Earth? Or bigger? I'd think they'd have to be pretty big to attract all that gas when the planets were being formed.

**edit** I'm writing a short story and the setting consists of late eighties/early nineties type of technology and knowledge of astronomy, so a rough estimate as an answer is fine

Comment: This looks like something you can easily look up.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Internal_structure) tells you as much as we know, which is very little.

Comment: @StephenG [This abstract seems to hold the information I needed.](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1982P&SS...30..755S)

Comment: Search for "formation of Jupiter pdf" and you'll get a feel for how many theories and variations on them there are for the formation of gas giants.  Lots. :-)

Comment: Wikipedia suggests the question of what materials and in which phase state comprise the core of Jupiter is less than settled.

Comment: @harada  That abstract is from 1982, before supercomputers.   While 10-30 earth masses isn't necessarily a bad estimate, I'd look for something more recent if you want scientist's best current estimate.  Wiki says 12-45.  But rocky/ice core includes elements like Oxygen and Nitrogen.

Comment: @userLTK True, but for my purposes, a rough estimate would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10-30 Earth masses is an estimate from [this abstract](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1982P&SS...30..755S), but [12-45](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter#Internal_structure) is a more accurate answer.

Comment: That gives an answer, supported by a source. The nature of the question is that it doesn't need much explanation.